# Qual a origem da palavra brasileira "Cortiço"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, origem-histórica

Qual a origem da palavra "Cortiço"?

Eu que não sou do Brasil tenho muitas dúvidas.
Significa o mesmo que "pensão/residencial" em Portugal?
Arvore da cortica sobreiro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cortiço vem de cortiça, que é a casca morta de uma árvore chamada sobreiro. Essa casca tem características muito singulares, é porosa e leve, espessa e isolante. Por conta disso, os humanos logo inventaram inúmeros meios de utilizá-la no dia a dia. Um desses usos foi o de abrigar abelhas. Colmeias inteiras podem ser realojadas para conveniência dos apicultores. Essas cascas abrigam centenas de abelhas, daí fez-se o paralelo com a nossa espécie. Um cortiço é uma casa onde vivem muitas pessoas, ou então um aglomerado de casas para pessoas pobres.

Não sei como são chamados em Portugal, mas aqui no Brasil são coisas diferentes. Uma pensão é uma casa familiar que aluga quartos a médio e longo prazo.

Comment: A palavra é cortiça.

Comment: Foi a primeira coisa que disse. Cortiço vem do radical depreendido de cortiça, com alteração do -a final para -o.